# Can't use spotipy even though I installed it

Tags: python, spotipy

I installed spotipy on my laptop using `pip install spotify`
at cmd. I checked that spotipy was successfully installed using `pip install check`.

*pip install spotify error message*
[image: pip install spotify error message]

*result of pip list*
[image: result of pip list]

However, when I try to use spotify on kaggle, I get an error message that says there is no module named spotify.

I had similar issues with jupyter notebook. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

When you install a package using pip, you get to use it through Python. Spotipy isn't a CLI tool, and cannot be accessed by simply typing it on cmd. If you were to open up a Python terminal and try `import spotipy`, it would import properly.

Consider the [block of code](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/master/#welcome-to-spotipy) on the official Spotipy doc. It imports Spotipy, then uses it within the code itself:

```
import spotipy
...

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials())
results = spotify.artist_albums(birdy_uri, album_type='album')
```

Also consider reading up on Python packages and how they work.